# Assigning excel function to a variable in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign am excel function to a VBA variable. I have tried a few different data types and none of them seem to work. I am trying to count the columns and rows in this table "tblAdsorpsionColumn" and I dont want to type out "Application.WorksheetFunction" every time I use an excel function in VBA. I know there other ways to do this but I want to use this way to learn how to use this functionality later. (what doesn't work: Worksheet,Double,String,Object)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim App As Object
    Dim Table As Range

    Set App = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set Table = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("tblAdsorpsionColumn")

    lstTable.ColumnCount = App.Columns(Table)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're in VBA then `Range("tblAdsorpsionColumn").Columns.Count` would be better

Answer (score 0):

Say you use the `SUM()` worksheet function frequently in VBA and don't want to repeat typing Application.WorksheetFunction constantly.  Just make a VBA wrapper like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function summ(rng As Range) As Variant
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        summ = .Sum(rng)
    End With
End Function
```

You will get a very small performance hit using it, but it may be tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to "shortcut" `Application.WorksheetFunction` :

```
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print wsf.Average(Selection), wsf.Sum(Selection)
End Sub

Function wsf() As Object
    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
End Function
```

Comment: With this, do you not have to declare what "wsf" is?

Comment: No - wsf is the function named "wsf", so it's already declared